# Error while iterating through AWS workspaces using for loop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

So I have been trying to use a for loop in python function but it keeps on throwing error:

```
"errorMessage": "'dict' object is not callable","errorType": "TypeError"
```

I am trying to iterate through the aws workspaces using lambda function to detect the unhealthy  workspaces using state and since the response of 'describe_workspaces' api is a dict, I am not able to figure out how to do the iterations.

Below is my code

```py
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('workspaces')
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
    response = client.describe_workspaces(
        WorkspaceIds = ['ws-8hy50vsm0','ws-jx4zr56wv','ws-08qhmql31']
    )
        
    print(response)

    for i in response['Workspaces']:
        if(i['State']== 'STOPPED'):
            print(i['WorkspaceId'])
            client.start_workspaces(i['WorkspaceId'])
```

Comment: Right now, the error is at `for i in response('Workspaces'):`. Even if I remove `client.reboot_workspaces(i['WorkspaceId'])` and just print the value, it'll throw the same error.

Comment: Ah, ok.  In that case, look at `response`, which is probably a `dict`.  Maybe you want `reponse['Workspaces']`, i.e. square brackets instead of parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one commentator already noted, the problem is your `for` loop. You need to use brackets (`[]`) instead of parentheses (`()`).

| Wrong | Right |
| --- | --- |
| `for i in response('Workspaces'):` | `for i in response['Workspaces']:` |

Comment: Yes, Thank you. It worked. Could you please also look into the `client.start_workspaces(i['WorkspaceId'])` as I am trying to start the workspaces where State= 'STOPPED'. Thanks

Comment: @AnshikaTyagi You did not write what it is wrong with `start_workspaces` etc. But even then, at Stackoverflow we do not answer multiple different questions at the same time. You question was about iterating the dictionary. This would be a different question. Please create a new question and provide all the required information: what are you trying to do, your code, what you expect, what actually happens, any error messages etc.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. This makes sense. :)